# Check uploaded file is a image or not using asp.net web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, filereader

I'd like to check the uploaded file is an image or not using asp.net web api. I send a JSON string object from client side to web API. I can read the data of the uploaded file from server side, it's like "����\u0000\u0010JFIF\u0000\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0000H\u0000H\u0000\u0000��"

Javascript code like this:

```
       var file = document.getElementById("UploadFile").files[0];

        if (file) {

            var fileReader = new FileReader();

            fileReader.readAsText(file, "UTF-8");

            fileReader.onload = function (evt) {

                $scope.BookingForm.Extension.FileContent = fileReader.result;

                $scope.BookingForm.Extension.FileName = file.name;
                $scope.BookingForm.Extension.FileSize = file.size;
```

fileReader.result is data of file.
And here is ajax code to post data to web api.

```
    var fromdata = JSON.stringify($scope.BookingForm);
    var requestUrl = "/webapp/api/onlineform/PostOnlineForm"
    return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: requestUrl,
        data: fromdata,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json; odata=verbose"
        }
    });
```

And here is the function from server side:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostOnlineForm(OnlineForm formData)
        {
            Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject extensionObj = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(formData.Extensions);
            var dataOfFile = extensionObj["FileContent"].ToString();

            // code here

        }
```

with variable "dataOfFile" is the string data of an uploaded file.
I'd like to check variable "dataOfFile" is an image or not. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Check the file for a [file signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures) (the following code `IsImage()` checks for BMP, GIF, PNG, TIFF, JPEG)

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool IsImage(this byte[] fileBytes)
    {
        if (fileBytes.Length < 2)
        {
            return false;
        }

        var headers = new List<byte[]>
        {
            new byte[] { 0x42, 0x4D }, // BMP
            new byte[] { 0x47, 0x49, 0x46, 0x38, 0x37, 0x61 }, // GIF
            new byte[] { 0x47, 0x49, 0x46, 0x38, 0x39, 0x61 }, // GIF
            new byte[] { 0x89, 0x50, 0x4e, 0x47, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x1A, 0x0A }, // PNG
            new byte[] { 0x49, 0x49, 0x2A, 0x00 }, // TIFF
            new byte[] { 0x4D, 0x4D, 0x00, 0x2A }, // TIFF
            new byte[] { 0xFF, 0xD8, 0xFF }, // JPEG
            new byte[] { 0xFF, 0xD9 }, // JPEG
        };

        return headers.Any(x => x.SequenceEqual(fileBytes.Take(x.Length)));
    }
}
```

Your server side function would become

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostOnlineForm(OnlineForm formData)
{
    Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject extensionObj = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(formData.Extensions);
    var dataOfFile = extensionObj["FileContent"].ToString();
    
    // get first 8 bytes        
    int length = Math.Min(8, Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(dataOfFile));
    byte[] fileBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dataOfFile, 0, length); 

    bool isImage = fileBytes.IsImage();
}
```

By the way, posting file content in json body is not the best way to upload files. Consider [File upload scenarios](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-5.0#file-upload-scenarios).

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I got the issue "Cannot convert from string to char[]" at line  `byte[] fileBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dataOfFile, 0, length); `

Comment: `GetBytes(String, Int32, Int32)` overload is only available in .NET Core. Try to use  `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dataOfFile)` instead.

Comment: @VõTháiPhúc, did it fix your problem?

Comment: Much appreciated for your help, but it's still not working.